# I cannot disable a ListView item when I use an AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I have a Listview and a

setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() on it.

I click and an AlertDialog warns me if I trully want to disable this item or not.

```
listCustomer.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            if (listCustomer.getChildAt(position).isEnabled()) {


                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DisplayDiscounts.this);
                builder.setTitle("Confirmation");

                builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
                builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



                db = new DbHelper(getBaseContext());
                Customer myCustomerWithDiscount = db.getCustomer(Integer.parseInt(CustomerId));
                String discount_credits = txtdiscount_credits.getText().toString();
                myCustomerWithDiscount.setCredits(myCustomerWithDiscount.getCredits() - Integer.parseInt(discount_credits));
                db.updateCustomer(myCustomerWithDiscount);

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listCustomerDiscounts.setAdapter(adapter);
                        listCustomerDiscounts.getChildAt(position).setEnabled(false);
                        db.closeDB();


                    listCustomer.getChildAt(position).setEnabled(false);

                    }
                });
                builder.show();

            }
        }
    });
```

If I click Yes then I get NullPointerException on null object reference **what is getting null here?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following changes and let me know if works?

**NOTE**
If does not work, I'll delete the answer. I'm putting here since it is too big to add it in the comments:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {

    if (view.isEnabled()) {
        ...
        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                view.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
}});
```

**Your code may not work well**

You are using a ListView and the views are re-used. This way, eventually, a disabled View may be used in a position which should receive a enabled view (and vice-versa)....

This is easy to check if you do following test:

- Disable first view...
- Then, scroll until a non-visible item becomes visible...
- Then, you will note that one view may appear disabled also (but you disabled only the first view).

So, in fact, you should use a different approach:

**Best Way**

Note, this is just an example... Just to share the idea:

Activity.java

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {

    if (view.isEnabled()) {
        ...
        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Inform the adapter that following item should be disabled
                mAdapter.setEnableState(position, false);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
}});
```

Adapter.java

```
public void setEnableState(int position, boolean state) {
    // boolean array to track view states
    arrayWithStateOfViews[position] = state;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    .....

    // Following code could be simplified to convertView.setEnabled(arrayWithStateOfViews[position])
    if(arrayWithStateOfViews[position] == true)
        convertView.setEnabled(true);
    else
        convertView.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: Its disabled okay but the notifydatasetChanged is not updating the listview item.